# r markdown kable break table width into multiple tables below each other

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a way to tell `kable` to break a long table (that would exceed the text or page width) into multiple ones that are shown below each other?

I mean, you can do this like this:

````
```{r}
data <- data.frame(....)
kable(data[,1:6])
kable(data[,7:12])
```
````

But this is a lot of work in figuring out where to break the data.frame. Is there a way to do it automatically? I found no option in the `kable` function itself.

One way to do it computationally is to calculate the string width of the longest entries in the table (and the header) and break the table depending on this. But I still hope there is already a good way to do it...

Optimally I would like to do this for html page generation, but a way to do it for latex would also be great.

Comment: `xtable` and `pixiedust` both provide options for using the LaTeX package `longtable`, which will break up tables that exceed the length of the page. `pixiedust` can mimic that behavior in HTML and word.  I'm not sure if `xtable` can do it in html.  But I'm not aware of any package that can automate this for the width of the table in either R or LaTeX.

Comment: yeah, from the example in the man page of kable I saw that it can also be used with longtable: `kable(matrix(1000, ncol = 5), format = "latex", digits = 2, longtable = TRUE)`. Good to know that `pixiedust` can do the same in html and word. But yeah, this breaks only if the length exceeds the page, not the width.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`pander`](http://rapporter.github.io/pander) can do this for you and many more -- quick example on the split table feature with directly specified function arguments (see `?pandoc.table` for more details, which is called by the general `pander` S3 method in the background):

```
> pander(head(mtcars), split.table = 80, style = 'rmarkdown')

|         &nbsp;          |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |  drat  |
|:-----------------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|:------:|
|      **Mazda RX4**      |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |  3.9   |
|    **Mazda RX4 Wag**    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |  3.9   |
|     **Datsun 710**      | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |  3.85  |
|   **Hornet 4 Drive**    | 21.4  |   6   |  258   | 110  |  3.08  |
|  **Hornet Sportabout**  | 18.7  |   8   |  360   | 175  |  3.15  |
|       **Valiant**       | 18.1  |   6   |  225   | 105  |  2.76  |

Table: Table continues below

|         &nbsp;          |  wt   |  qsec  |  vs  |  am  |  gear  |  carb  |
|:-----------------------:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|:----:|:------:|:------:|
|      **Mazda RX4**      | 2.62  | 16.46  |  0   |  1   |   4    |   4    |
|    **Mazda RX4 Wag**    | 2.875 | 17.02  |  0   |  1   |   4    |   4    |
|     **Datsun 710**      | 2.32  | 18.61  |  1   |  1   |   4    |   1    |
|   **Hornet 4 Drive**    | 3.215 | 19.44  |  1   |  0   |   3    |   1    |
|  **Hornet Sportabout**  | 3.44  | 17.02  |  0   |  0   |   3    |   2    |
|       **Valiant**       | 3.46  | 20.22  |  1   |  0   |   3    |   1    |
```

You can set a global threshold for the number of characters via [global options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) among many other things, eg:

```
> panderOptions('table.split.table', 80)
> panderOptions('table.style', 'grid')
> panderOptions('table.split.cells', 10)
> panderOptions('table.alignment.default', 'left')
> panderOptions('table.alignment.rownames', 'right')
> panderOptions('decimal.mark', ',')
> pander(head(mtcars))

+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+
|         &nbsp; | mpg   | cyl   | disp   | hp   | drat   | wt    |
+================+=======+=======+========+======+========+=======+
|        **Mazda | 21    | 6     | 160    | 110  | 3,9    | 2,62  |
|          RX4** |       |       |        |      |        |       |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+
|        **Mazda | 21    | 6     | 160    | 110  | 3,9    | 2,875 |
|      RX4 Wag** |       |       |        |      |        |       |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+
|       **Datsun | 22,8  | 4     | 108    | 93   | 3,85   | 2,32  |
|          710** |       |       |        |      |        |       |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+
|     **Hornet 4 | 21,4  | 6     | 258    | 110  | 3,08   | 3,215 |
|        Drive** |       |       |        |      |        |       |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+
|       **Hornet | 18,7  | 8     | 360    | 175  | 3,15   | 3,44  |
|   Sportabout** |       |       |        |      |        |       |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+
|    **Valiant** | 18,1  | 6     | 225    | 105  | 2,76   | 3,46  |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+------+--------+-------+

Table: Table continues below

+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|         &nbsp; | qsec   | vs   | am   | gear   | carb   |
+================+========+======+======+========+========+
|        **Mazda | 16,46  | 0    | 1    | 4      | 4      |
|          RX4** |        |      |      |        |        |
+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|        **Mazda | 17,02  | 0    | 1    | 4      | 4      |
|      RX4 Wag** |        |      |      |        |        |
+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|       **Datsun | 18,61  | 1    | 1    | 4      | 1      |
|          710** |        |      |      |        |        |
+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|     **Hornet 4 | 19,44  | 1    | 0    | 3      | 1      |
|        Drive** |        |      |      |        |        |
+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|       **Hornet | 17,02  | 0    | 0    | 3      | 2      |
|   Sportabout** |        |      |      |        |        |
+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
|    **Valiant** | 20,22  | 1    | 0    | 3      | 1      |
+----------------+--------+------+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Can we do the same with xtable?

Comment: @skan I'd ask that in a separate question